# Object doesn't support this property or method ReceivedTime

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am new to VB code and I am trying to execute the below code. But I get an error message object doesn't support this property or method at this line

```
If VBA.DateValue(VBA.Now) - VBA.DateValue(Folder.Items.Item(iRow).ReceivedTime) <= 60 Then
```

I think my code is not reading the `ReceivedTime`. I am using Microsoft Excel 2010. How do I fix it?

```
Option Explicit

Sub Download_Outlook_Mail_To_Excel()
    'Add Tools->References->"Microsoft Outlook nn.n Object Library"
    'nn.n varies as per our Outlook Installation
    Dim Folder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim sFolders As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim iRow As Integer, oRow As Integer
    Dim MailBoxName As String, Pst_Folder_Name  As String

    'Mailbox or PST Main Folder Name (As how it is displayed in your Outlook Session)
    MailBoxName = "xxxx@yyyy.com"

    'Mailbox Folder or PST Folder Name (As how it is displayed in your Outlook Session)
    Pst_Folder_Name = "Inbox" 'Sample "Inbox" or "Sent Items"

    'To directly a Folder at a high level
    Set Folder = Outlook.Session.Folders(MailBoxName).Folders(Pst_Folder_Name)

    'To access a main folder or a subfolder (level-1)
    For Each Folder In Outlook.Session.Folders(MailBoxName).Folders
        If VBA.UCase(Folder.Name) = VBA.UCase(Pst_Folder_Name) Then GoTo Label_Folder_Found
        For Each sFolders In Folder.Folders
            If VBA.UCase(sFolders.Name) = VBA.UCase(Pst_Folder_Name) Then
                Set Folder = sFolders
                GoTo Label_Folder_Found
            End If
        Next sFolders
    Next Folder

Label_Folder_Found:
     If Folder.Name = "" Then
        MsgBox "Invalid Data in Input"
        GoTo End_Lbl1:
    End If

    'Read Through each Mail and export the details to Excel for Email Archival
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Activate
    Folder.Items.Sort "Received"

    'Insert Column Headers
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1) = "Body"

    'Export eMail Data from PST Folder
    oRow = 1
    For iRow = 1 To Folder.Items.Count
        'If condition to import mails received in last 60 days
        'To import all emails, comment or remove this IF condition
        If VBA.DateValue(VBA.Now) - VBA.DateValue(Folder.Items.Item(iRow).ReceivedTime) <= 60 Then

         '  ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(oRow, 1).Select
           oRow = oRow + 1
           ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(oRow, 1) = Folder.Items.Item(iRow).Body
        End If
    Next iRow
    MsgBox "Outlook Mails Extracted to Excel"
    Set Folder = Nothing
    Set sFolders = Nothing

End_Lbl1:
End Sub
```

Comment: You really need to include the value of `ReceivedTime` in order that we can see how you are using `DateValue` to parse it. The [DateValue function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278648.aspx) (or possibly the [TimeValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hz2ahtzs%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)) is intended to convert a strng that looks like a date or time to an actual date or time value (e.g. numeric).

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are encountering an item other than MailItem, most likely ReportItem, which does not expose the ReceivedTime property.

Add an extra check for the Class property (exposed by all Outlook objects) to be 43 (olMail).

On a side note, you are using multiple dot notation, which is a really bad idea:

```
   dim vItems as Outlook.Items 
   dim vItem As Object

   set vItems =  Folder.Items
   For iRow = 1 To vItems.Count
           set vItem = vItems.Item(iRow) 
           if vItem.Class = 43 Then
                'If condition to import mails received in last 60 days
                'To import all emails, comment or remove this IF condition
                If VBA.DateValue(VBA.Now) - VBA.DateValue(vItem.ReceivedTime) <= 60 Then
                   oRow = oRow + 1
                   ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(oRow, 1) = vItem.Body
                End If
            End If
     Next iRow
```

Comment: Hi, Now my code gives an error saying vItems not defined.

Comment: I did not declare any variables for the sake of brevity. See the updates answer above.